# Wordpress Media Library rendering blank image tiles

Tags: htaccess, media-library

Problem: I have been experiencing an error with all my images on my site. When I navigate to my website in any browser, none of the images are rendering. When I login to my admin portal and navigate the the media library, all the images are showing blank thumbnails. When I FTP into my site and view my uploads directory, all the images are there and I can view them just fine.

I am running on Wordpress 5.1.1, just using a single site install. I have not updated any plugins this week or posted anything so I am perplexed as to why this issue is occurring.

Troubleshooting:

-Disabled each plugin one-by-one to see if they were interfering, however, this didn't yield any result.

-Verified my permissions in my uploads directory. Folders: 744. Files: 644.

-Updated Theme. No change.

-Switched to different theme. No change.

-Restored site from a previous backup. No change.

-Reinstalled WP core 5.1.1. No Change.

-Used Wordpress Health Check plug-in in troubleshooting mode. While in this mode, images still not rendering.

I am currently working with my hosting provider and they are going to be restoring from a backup that was further back.

I do have some errors in my cpanel error log. I am getting the following errors multiple times:

```
Permission Denied: ..../public_html/wp-content/uploads/.htaccess pcfg_openfile: unable to check htaccess file. Ensure it is readable and that /uploads is executable.
```

Also this:

```
Error: mmap cache can't open ..../public_html/wp-includes/load.php - Permission Denied
```

Could the htaccess file error be the reason why images in my uploads folder are not loading?

Does anyone have any other troubleshooting tips I can perform in the meantime?

Comment: Inspect the image path in your browser by hitting f12 and selecting image.

Comment: Yes, I have used the inspect feature, however, usually there is an image placeholder if the image won't load, but there is not placeholder at all for my images so I am unable to inspect the image path.

Comment: Do you have 404 errors in the console?  You should still be able to inspect the image if you look through the HTML in the inspector.  Did you change your site name recently (Admin > Settings > General) or add an SSL?

Comment: I have no 404 errors in the console. I renewed my SSL cert 1 month ago with no issues. Site name has not changed. I have gone through the HTML in the inspector and did a search for img and the only image that is loading is my logo which is in the header.

Comment: If you copy the URL of the image and put it directly into your browser, does the image show?

Comment: @aryxus Yes, I am able to use the full image url and it renders on my browser. eg: mywebsite/wp-content/uploads/2019/02/imagefilename.jpg. I have used this to test  random images in my uploads folder and they all work.

Comment: Can you upload an image of your inspect console when the page loads? I've seen something like this before, but in Chrome it would show a bunch of 'Failed to load resource' errors.

Comment: I don't get any Failed to load resource errors in my console while the page loads. I just get a google maps javascript api key warning message.